# Multiple condition search function in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, search

I'm trying to search values with dropdown value and daterange.
But it works for only one at a time. Like if I select a value from dropdown and select daterange it doesn't show.

Here is my code

Controller:

```
public function sale_index(request $request){

    $users = User::orderBy( 'fname', 'asc')->get();
    $sales = Sim::where('stock', '>', 0)->orderBy( 'id', 'desc')->get();

    if($request->filled('search')){
        $sales = Sim::where('user_id', '=', $request->search)->orderBy( 'id', 'desc')->get();
    }
    if($request->filled('from') AND $request->filled('to')){
        $sales = Sim::whereBetween('created_at', [$request->get('from'), $request->get('to')])->orderBy( 'id', 'desc')->get();
    }

    return view('admin.all_sale', compact('sales','users'));
}
```

Blade file:

```
  <form action="" method="GET">
        <select name="search" id="">
            <option value="">Seller Name</option>
            @foreach ( $users as  $row)
              <option value="{{ $row->id }}" @if ($row->id == request()->query('search'))
                selected
                @else
              @endif >{{ $row->fname }} {{ $row->lname }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <input type="date" name="from">
        <input type="date" name="to">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
```

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two conditions are overwriting with a different query, instead of combining the `where` filters all as one query.

Try changing this:

```
$sales = Sim::where('stock', '>', 0)->orderBy( 'id', 'desc')->get();

if($request->filled('search')){
    $sales = Sim::where('user_id', '=', $request->search)->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
}
if($request->filled('from') AND $request->filled('to')){
    $sales = Sim::whereBetween('created_at', [$request->get('from'), $request->get('to')])->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
}
```

To this: (the change replaces `$sales =` to `$sales->` to the `where` clauses)

```
$sales = Sim::where('stock', '>', 0)->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');

if($request->filled('search')){
    $sales->orWhere('user_id', '=', $request->search)->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
}
if($request->filled('from') AND $request->filled('to')){
    $sales->orWhereBetween('created_at', [$request->get('from'), $request->get('to')])->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
}

$sales->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its not working. Is there any better way to make search. I have a table where I need to search with username and a daterange.

Comment: Ok, it seems that an `or`ing search is needed instead of `and`? ... Anyway, please try the updated example, the updated change is using `orWhere` and `orWhereBetween`.

Comment: It shows this error

Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere does not exist.

Comment: What version of Laravel do you have?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 7

Comment: Oh, apologies! ... I forgot about the `->get()` on the three original `Sim::` queries -- which caused the `orWhere` to error on the `collection` in the first condition. See the updated code for all `$sales` lines. Now there's only one `->get();`, which is moved last after the conditions and all the query needs have been gathered.